# Weird C# / F# difference in a declaration, code compiling in C# but not in F#

Tags: c#, f#, influxdb

The line is to instantiate a queue of data points for the InfluxDB driver:

C#

```
Events = new ConcurrentQueue<InfluxDatapoint<InfluxValueField>>();
```

F#

```
let Events = new ConcurrentQueue<InfluxDatapoint<InfluxValueField>>()
```

in C#, it compiles without problem, but in F#, I get this:

> [FS0001] The type 'InfluxValueField' is not compatible with the type 'IComparable'

Following the comment from canton7, here is the source for both external elements:

InfluxValueField: https://github.com/AdysTech/InfluxDB.Client.Net/blob/master/src/DataStructures/InfluxValueField.cs

InfluxDataPoint: https://github.com/AdysTech/InfluxDB.Client.Net/blob/master/src/DataStructures/InfluxDatapoint.cs

What could cause it to compile in C# but not in F#?

---

Edit:

Here are two code examples:

C#

```
namespace A
{
    using System.Collections.Concurrent;
    using AdysTech.InfluxDB.Client.Net;

    public class test
    {
        public test()
        {
            var Events = new ConcurrentQueue<InfluxDatapoint<InfluxValueField>>();
        }
    }
}
```

F#

```
namespace A

open System.Collections.Concurrent
open AdysTech.InfluxDB.Client.Net

    module B =
        let Events = new ConcurrentQueue<InfluxDatapoint<InfluxValueField>>()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and include the definition of `InfluxDatapoint`.

Comment: Note, the source of `InfluxValueField` [is here](https://github.com/AdysTech/InfluxDB.Client.Net/blob/master/src/DataStructures/InfluxValueField.cs), and `InfluxDataPoint` [is here](https://github.com/AdysTech/InfluxDB.Client.Net/blob/master/src/DataStructures/InfluxDatapoint.cs)

Comment: I just added examples

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18094374/1688785

Comment: the link for InfluxValueField is invalid for me. is it a `IComparable, IComparable<T>`?

Comment: @Caramiriel: I think it could very well be the case. I need to re-read that answer to make sure I understand all details though :)

Comment: @Dongdong: you can use the link canton7 put in the second comment. I will edit the question to point to the source properly

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to program to interfaces instead of implementations. So use an interface as the generic type parameter, instead of a concrete type.

```
open AdysTech.InfluxDB.Client.Net
open System.Collections.Concurrent

let events = ConcurrentQueue<IInfluxDatapoint>()
let event1 = InfluxDatapoint<IInfluxValueField>()
let field1a = InfluxValueField(42.99)
let field1b = InfluxValueField("a message")
let event2 = InfluxDatapoint<IInfluxValueField>()
let field2a = InfluxValueField(0.05)

let addEvents () = 
    event1.Fields.Add("amountRequestedUSD", field1a)
    event1.Fields.Add("message", field1b)
    events.Enqueue(event1)
    event2.Fields.Add("someDouble", field2a)
    events.Enqueue(event2)
```

Comment: this is not working, it returns the error: The type 'IComparable' is not compatible with the type 'IComparable<IComparable>'

Comment: To help I would need to see the code and what line is giving that error.

Comment: The error comes from a straight copy / paste from the line in the solution. I put a code sample there: https://pastebin.com/VbBTuQRe

Comment: If you know the underlying type of the `InfluxValueField` value is int (for instance), then you could do this: `let Event1 = ConcurrentQueue<InfluxDatapoint<int>>()`

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not the case; this is used to push a variety of values to database so there is a variety of types accepted.

Comment: I wonder if this is the problem: https://github.com/AdysTech/InfluxDB.Client.Net/issues/7
Maybe F# is warning you at compile-time that "InfluxDataPoint fields cannot be different types"; whereas C# might wait until run-time.

Comment: InfluxDB has data in form of key,value<T> so for every value, you will instantiate a new InfluxDataPoint<T>, possibly with a different T (string vs. float for example); could this work differently in F#? (as a beginner in F#, I don't know much about the generics there)

Comment: Try this (note `IInfluxDatapoint` instead of `InfluxDatapoint`): `let Event1 = ConcurrentQueue<IInfluxDatapoint>()`

Comment: I followed this C# example code: https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/InfluxDatapoint/-/php-influxdatapoint-class-examples.html#0xf3896054c7e5a9afb49b59b2c695681161acadd5619868ee8c6a3f280398d1db-440,,507,

Comment: this is an example of working code from the C# I'm trying to port to F#: https://pastebin.com/H7AphJaW

Comment: OK. I don't think that conflicts with my last suggestion.

Comment: I think the issue is that I don't understand the root of the error itself; It don't get if it means that InfluxValueField<T> must implement IComparable, or that T must implement it.

Comment: I think the problem is that InfluxDatapoint<T> wants a type that implements BOTH IComparable AND IComparable<T>.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202839/discussion-between-thomas-and-scott-hutchinson).