# InfluxValueField that implements two interfaces incompatible in F#

Tags: f#, influxdb

Referencing the Nuget package `AdysTech.InfluxDB.Client.Net.Core`, this code will not compile. How can I change it to make it compile?

```
open AdysTech.InfluxDB.Client.Net

let event1 = InfluxDatapoint<'T>()
let field1 = InfluxValueField(42.99) // :> IComparable<InfluxValueField>
let addFields () = 
    event1.Fields.Add("amountRequestedUSD", field1) // //Error  FS0001  The type 'InfluxValueField' is not compatible with the type 'IComparable<InfluxValueField>'.
```

The definition of `IInfluxValueField` is [public interface IInfluxValueField : IComparable, IComparable of IInfluxValueField](https://github.com/AdysTech/InfluxDB.Client.Net/blob/master/src/DataStructures/IInfluxValueField.cs#L5).

The definition of `InfluxValueField` is [public class InfluxValueField : IInfluxValueField](https://github.com/AdysTech/InfluxDB.Client.Net/blob/master/src/DataStructures/InfluxValueField.cs#L7).

It seems that F# is having trouble coping with this type that implements two interfaces, but of course it should not have any trouble with it.

You can also get the solution containing this code at https://github.com/ScottHutchinson/InfluxDBFSharpClient

This is a simplified version of the question at [Weird C# / F# difference in a declaration, code compiling in C# but not in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58936062/5652483)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A member of the F# Software Foundation provides this answer.

```
open AdysTech.InfluxDB.Client.Net

let event1 = InfluxDatapoint<IInfluxValueField>()
let field1 = InfluxValueField(42.99)
let addFields () = 
    event1.Fields.Add("amountRequestedUSD", field1)
```